# Gradle task to run another task with multiple arguments

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, vert.x

I was wondering if it's possible to create a gradle task to run another task with multiple arguments in parallel. This specific tasks are deploying and running Vertx verticles, deploying them individually, but I wanted a way to run all verticles at the same time through gradle.

I tried the code snip bellow, but can't seem to make it work. Couldn't make sense of the WorkerApi stuff, so I'm wondering if anyone had a similar use case before.

here's what I tried so far:

```
task runVerticlesThroughLauncher(type: JavaExec) {
//this task is the main task that uses the VerticleLauncher to initialize a verticle and deploy it.

    if (project.hasProperty("launcherNames")) {
        ext.cmdargs = project.getProperty("launcherNames")
    } else {
        ext.cmdargs = ""
    }

    def verticleRunCommands=[
      verticle1="com.verticles.Verticle1", 
      verticle2="com.verticles.Verticle2", 
      verticle3="com.verticles.Verticle3"
    ]

    File runningDir = new File('..')
    runningDir.mkdirs()
    tasks.runVerticlesThroughLauncher.workingDir(runningDir)

    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    mainClass = "com.main.VerticleLauncher"
    args "run", verticleRunCommands.getOrDefault(cmdargs, "")
}

task runVerticleLauncherAllVerticles(type: JavaExec){
    // this task was my attempt at running all the verticles in parallel, but the task is not runnable, giving ClassNotFound error

    def verticles=[
            "verticle1", "verticle2", "verticle3"
    ].parallelStream().forEach(verticle -> {
        runContentProviderLauncher.args(verticle).exec()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it might look something like this:

```
task launchVerticles {
   List<String> verticles = ["verticle1", "verticle2", "verticle3"]
   doLast {
      verticles.parrallelStream().forEach( { verticle ->
         new JavaExec().with {
            mainClass = "com.main.VerticleLauncher"
            classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
            args = [verticle, "run", verticleRunCommands.getOrDefault(cmdargs, "") ]
            exec()
         }
      } as Consumer<String>)
   }
}
```

So tasks aren't functions.  They don't have arguments, and you can't invoke them like functions.  But they are classes and you can use them just like objects which I'm doing.  It's a little unconventional, but I think in your case it's ok.  What you don't want to do is create tasks dynamically within your gradle script which is what your requirements would be.  Plus the wrinkle of doing things in parallel.  Gradle supports running tasks in parallel with the `--parallel` option, but you have to set things up carefully.  Now if you created your own plugin dynamic tasks are totally on the table. But consider if you had a Verticle plugin you might do something like this:

```
task verticle1( type: VerticleTask ) {
   name = "verticle1"
}

task verticle2( type: VerticleTask ) {
   name = "verticle2"
}

task verticle3( type: VerticleTask ) {
   name = "verticle3"
}

task runVerticles {
   dependsOn("verticle1", "verticle2", "verticle3" )
}
```

Then launch with with the `--parallel` option, and it would work.  A VerticleTask might look like:

```
class VerticleTask extends JavaExec {

   @Input
   String name

   @Input
   List<String> verticleArgs = []

   @TaskAction
   @Override
   public void exec() {
      mainClass = "com.main.VerticleLauncher"
      classpath = project.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
      args = [name, "run", verticleArgs ].flatten()
      super.exec()
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it worked to an extent, however it tries to run each verticle one at a time, so doesn;t solve the main problem

Comment: Which version are you referring to?  The first option used parrallelStream which should definitely run those in parallel.  The 2nd one in hindsight probably isn't going to work parallel because of the removal of @ParallellTask annotation in groovy 4.x.  If you want to do this you'll have to use the WorkerAPI if the 1st option isn't satisfactory.